# Boost cpp_dec_float supports modulus operation

Tags: c++, boost, modulus, arbitrary-precision

As the title says, does Boost's `cpp_dec_float` support modulus operations? I'm dealing with money and would like to do some modulus operations to get the number of bills and coins that I need to return. `cpp_dec_float` seems to be the only arbitrary precision class that supports base 10.

Comment: You should not really use floating-point types for money, even at high precision you will still have rounding errors. Instead the best way is some sort of [fixed point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) system.

Comment: Ah, I made the assumption because it was suggested under Wikipedia. Can you suggest any fixed point libraries for C++?

Comment: http://blog.haoliu.org/2014/06/07/coding-challenge-money-changer-with-c-boost-multiprecision-library/

Comment: @JoachimPileborg in fairness, when working with money, rounding is often both expected and required. Ideally, the method and rounding points are also well specified (this is where it gets interesting). So "at high precision" doesn't really mean much, as `$100/3` usually just means `$33.33` (or `$33.3333` for intermediate results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is coin distribution, can't you just do it without modulo?

Boost multiprecision does define fmod, trunc, mod etc. whenever possible for a backend type; Here's a working demo: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3072aa29a0074332)**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/number.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using Num = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<128>>;

int main()
{
    Num x("189.5307");

    for (Num denom : { 
            Num("500.00"),   Num("200.00"),   Num("100.00"),
             Num("50.00"),    Num("20.00"),    Num("10.00"),
              Num("5.00"),     Num("2.00"),     Num("1.00"),
              Num("0.50"),     Num("0.20"),     Num("0.10"),
              Num("0.05"),     Num("0.02"),     Num("0.01"),
        })
    {
        Num count = x/denom;

        if (count >= 1)
        {
            count = trunc(count);
            std::cout << count << " * " << std::right << std::setw(6) << denom.str(2, std::ios::fixed) << "\n";
            x -= denom * count;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Remainder: " << x << "\n";
}
```

I explicitly selected an "invalid" input value (one with excess precision for the denominations) so you can verify it handles them. I have not bothered with the case for negative amounts, but you can figure that out :)

```
1 * 100.00
1 *  50.00
1 *  20.00
1 *  10.00
1 *   5.00
2 *   2.00
1 *   0.50
1 *   0.02
1 *   0.01
Remainder: 0.0007
```

Comment: See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3072aa29a0074332)**

Comment: You're completely right. I don't even remember why I needed modulus operations for this program. Perhaps I was thinking of something else?

Comment: fmod seems to work, but mod does not seem to be a valid function. What is your source for the api? Also, what advantages are there wrapping number on top of cpp_dec_float?

Comment: By mod I meant `operator %`. `cpp_dec_float` is a _backend_, you need to adapt it to get the higher level features (i.e. you `pow`, `trunc`, `fmod`, trig functions, expression templates, streaming operations, convenient constructions, mixed arithmetics etc. In short: all the interoperability stuff is in the _front end_.). You can also adapt as rational numbers before wrapping in the number template.

Comment: hmm, I'm getting `no match for ‘operator%’` for `x % x`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you might have forgotten the "whenever possible" part. See e.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4667bc75112750a9